# What is your application versioning strategy?

Tags: versioning, strategy

I would be interested to get the SO community's opinions on the best application versioning strategy.

My questions:

1. How do you keep track of your application's version number? Do you have a formal definition of what each number/character in that version represents?
2. What do the different numbers/strings in the application's version mean for your app?
3. Do you use any automated updating system in your apps (e.g. something like Sparkle) and how good has it been behaving for you?
4. Do you have a separate update procedure for beta-testers or pre-release testers of your app?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> - How do you keep track of your
>     application's version number? Do you
>     have a formal definition of what each
>     number/character in that version
>     represents?
> - What do the different numbers/strings
>     in the application's version mean for
>     your app?

I use following:

```
AppName_<Major>.<Minor>.<Patch/Upgrade>.<BuildNo>
```

**Major** - Major version is a definite release of the product. It increased when there are significant changes in functionality.

**Minor** - Minor version is incremented when only new features or major bug fixes have been added.

**Upgrade/Patch** - Upgrade refers to the replacement of a product with a newer version of product.It is incremented only when upgrade is provided on designated major release.Patch version starts with 0 and incremented only when bug has been resolved.

**Build No** - Build Number is incremented when new build is created.

> - Do you use any automated updating
>     system in your apps (e.g. something
>     like Sparkle) and how good has it been
>     behaving for you?

We use building tool which automatically builds app at night which we call nightly build and this increases build number every time a build is created.

> - Do you have a separate update
>     procedure for beta-testers or
>     pre-release testers of your app?

No. Tester tests over nightly build at every morning which we call BAT(Build Acceptance Test) and verify nightly build.

Comment: Thanks Harry. How easy is it to keep track of that build number? How user friendly is it (e.g. when receiving feedback about a certain version)?

Comment: @Andrei: Build number is auto generated every time a new build is created using build tool. It is not that much confusing to read app name with version [AppName_1.0.0.159] so no problem with user friendliness in reading app name.

Answer (score 12):

Let me note first there seem to be no agreement on the "best" strategy. I can only share my experience on a current project.

1. The system version is defined manually in a build property. It happens when the team agrees on a new release. As additional versioning we use the build number which is automatically generated by the CI build
2. We loosely follow the Ubuntu naming scheme `YY.MM.version.patch_buildNumber` as we have found that Major.Minor versioning messes up customer expectations ;)
3. There are no automatic updates as the application has to be rolled out by adminstrators
4. The test releases are more frequent than GA releases, but that should be all.

Comment: Thanks kostja. Can you expand a bit on messing up customer expectations?

Comment: @Andrei In our experience, a change in the major version leads some customers to assume groundbreaking changes in almost every aspect of the application. Furthermore, it forces the developers to think in terms of major releases, unnecessarily holding back a release "are we really ready to roll 2.0?". With the ubuntu versioning it goes more like "does it roll? we ship!"

Comment: I use something similar to Ubuntu's with a slight variation: YYMM.major.minor.build

Answer (score 12):

I use [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) for my open source libraries and find it much easier to work with other libraries which do as well. It provides a common basis for understanding what a version change might mean. Is the library still in beta? Is a release just for bug fixes? Will there be breaking API changes?

It's basically a codification of the best versioning practices already used by most open source projects.

Answer (score 10):

I tested many version systems and now I'm pretty happy with this one:

> [major].[minor].[revision]

- **Major** is set manually and refer to a version including major improvements
- **Minor** is also set manually and refer to an upgrade/maintenance release, including minor improvements & fixes
- **Revision** is generated automatically and refer to an exact revision in the repository.

The last one allows us to be very flexible with versionning. We can ship multiple versions for multiple clients and still be able to debug & fix with ease by getting the specific version from the repos, then merge back with the trunk.

The build, packaging & publishing is fully automated. The only manual action is when we move the last package to the production server by FTP. We want to keep the control on that to ensure we don't deliver crap in production. It goes to a preliminary stage where early adopters can read the release notes and then decide to download and use the version. Customers that face specific bugs can get a fixed version very fast by using one of these versions.

Comment: +1 I've been using this method also, inspired by Apache guidelines: http://commons.apache.org/releases/versioning.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is to make sure a release has some unique number, so that you can easily identify it. How that number is broken down doesn't really matter. The version we use that I care about is major.minor.customerID.buildnumber. The buildnumber is autogenerated from our build script.